# Dynamic bool array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, boolean

```
// All right? This is really good working code? 
//Need init array with value "false"

bool **Madj;
int NodeCount=4;

bool **Madj = new bool*[NodeCount];
for (int i=0; i<NodeCount; i++){
    Madj[i] = new bool [NodeCount];
    for (int j=0; j<NodeCount; j++){
        Madj[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? What is the error and what is your question?

Comment: Yes, this will create a 4x4 matrix of booleans. No, it's not particularly good; `Madj` is declared twice without need and the code is prone to memory leaks.

Comment: @Emile: it does, but I'm not sure enough it doesn't belong here to vote to close. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is still in beta so we can't refer questions there.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using Boost's builtin [multi-dimensional array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) as a less brittle alternative.  As noted the code you supplied will work, but has issues.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool> >   Madj(4,std:vector<bool>(4, false));
```

Unfortunately std::vector<bool> is specialized to optimize for size (not speed).
So it can be inefficient (especially if used a lot). So you could use an int array (if you find the bool version is slowing you down).

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >   Madj(4,std:vector<int>(4, 0));
```

Note: int can be used in a boolean context and auto converted (0 => false, any other number is true (though best to use 1).

Answer (score 3):

At least IMO, if you insist on doing this at all, you should normally do it rather differently, something like:

```
class bool_array { 
     bool *data_;
     size_t width_;

     // no assignment or copying
     bool_array &operator=();
     bool_array(bool_array const &);
public:
     bool_array(size_t x, size_t y) width_(x) {
         data_ = new bool[x*y];
         std::fill_n(data_, x*y, false);
     }

     bool &operator()(size_t x, size_t y) { 
         return data_[y+width_+x];
     }

     ~bool_array() { delete [] data_; }
};
```

This can be embellished (e.g., using a proxy to enforce constness), but the general idea remains: 1) allocate your `bool`s in a single block, and 2) put them into a class, and 3) overload an operator to support reasonably clean indexing into the data.

You should also consider using `std::vector<bool>`. Unlike other instantiations of `std::vector`, it's not a container (as the standard defines that term), which can be confusing -- but what you're creating isn't a container either, so that apparently doesn't matter to you.

Comment: What is the potential danger of filling that using a for loop in case of a memory leak? Could you point me to some article about that on the web?

Comment: @Hossein: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Part of the idea of encapsulating it into an object is to ensure that memory *doesn't* leak.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool **Madj = new bool*[NodeCount];
for (int i=0; i<NodeCount; i++){
    Madj[i] = new bool [NodeCount];
    for (int j=0; j<NodeCount; j++){
        Madj[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

If the first call to `new` succeeds but any of the ones in the loop fails, you have a memory leak since `Madj` and the subarrays up to the current `i` are not deleted. Use a `vector<vector<bool> >`, or a `vector<bool>` of size `NodeCount * NodeCount`. With the latter option, you can get to element (`i`,`j`) with `[i*NodeCount+j]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks fine!

Depending on the use, you could use std::vector instead of a raw array.

But its true that the first Madj declaration should be "extern" to avoid linking or shadowing errors.

Comment: It's true, but they are only potential. If you have a vase on your desk it has potential to crash by dropping on the floor.

Comment: (referring to the memory leaks I pointed out; I since deleted the comment): you're defending the kind of sloppy programming that in today's world may cost big bucks or lives.

Comment: @larsmans The sloppy part is when you forget to reallocate the memory. Relying on automatic safeguards only moves the problem elsewhere. Memory leaks and crashes are only a tiny fraction of all the bugs around, and you don't have automatic safeguards for wrongly implemented logic. I totally support OP's code. I understand it creates a "risk" of a memory dealloc bug but every code line is a potential source for bugs.

Comment: The OP's code is not a potential source for bugs, it contains bugs.

Comment: @larsmans Does it contain some other bug than the duplicate declaration of Madj that would have been caught by the compiler-linker tool chain?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only `bool`s, consider using `bitset`s. You can combine that with other containers for multidimensional arrays, e.g `vector<bitset>`.